# border bottom to li with spans not working

Tags: css, border

I added a border-bottom style to li with spans inside but it's not working.

```
<ul>
<li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
<span class="col-xs-5">Test 1</span>
<span class="col-xs-7"> Test 2</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

It's rather straightforward, but it renders the border above the span (Test1, Test2). Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: how do you want the output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstraps `col-*` puts a float on the element. Bootstrap is built to handle this by wrapping columns with the `row` class. Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class='row' style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
    <span class="col-xs-5">Test 1</span>
    <span class="col-xs-7"> Test 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or you could put the `row` class on the `ul`, just depends on how you're using the `li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<ul>
  <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
    <span class="col-xs-5">Test 1</span>
  </li>
  <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
    <span class="col-xs-7"> Test 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
p {
        border-style: solid;
        border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li >
<span class="col-xs-5" >Test 1</span>
</li>
  <li >
<span class="col-xs-7"> Test 2</span>
</li>
</ul>
```